# How does Django delete the object from a view?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and my DeleteView is written like this:

```
class ObjectDelete(DeleteView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blah blah
        return super(ObjectDelete, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am confused as to how I will delete the object as I have not seen `object.delete` anywhere in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual deleting of objects is done by the [`DeletionMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L231), which is a parent of `django.views.generic.edit.BaseDeleteView` which the `DeleteView` uses.

Here is the [`DeletionMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L231):

```
class DeletionMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin providing the ability to delete objects
    """
    success_url = None

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Calls the delete() method on the fetched object and then
        redirects to the success URL.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    # Add support for browsers which only accept GET and POST for now.
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            return self.success_url
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")
```

It fetches the object to be deleted using `get_object()`.

Comment: but where is the line which tells what object to delete , what line triggers the delete